# auditing the user connectivity in PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

is it possible to find out when was the users last connected to DB, and stored it in a table for tracking purpose, by writing trigger on `pg_stat_activity` view.?

Thank you

Comment: you can log every connection to your database by pg_audit extension, I would instead build functionality on logs rather than writing a trigger on pg_stat_activity.
also, you can use log_connections and log_disconnections in postgresql.conf if you're only interested in connection logs

Comment: Turn log_connections on and check your logfiles (automatically).